# How do I set up typescript in Redux toolkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want to receive data from redux toolkit's createAsyncThunk when dispatching.

But I don't know how to set the data type.

If no data type is specified, a warning line is displayed with a red line.

like this Screenshot

[image]

How do I specify the type?

this is my code

```
    // commentinput is string and post.id is number

    const commetsubmitfun = useCallback(() => {
      dispatch(addComment({content: commentinput, postId: post.id}));
    }, [dispatch, commentinput]);




    export const addComment = createAsyncThunk(
      'post/addComment',
      async (data, {rejectWithValue}) => {
        try {
          //    data: {content: "aaa", postId: 66}
          const response = await axios.post(`/post/${data.postId}/comment`, data); // POST /post/1/comment
          return response.data;
        } catch (error: any) {
          return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
        }
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare type when calling `createAsyncThunk` ,
declare an interface for `data`
like this :

```
type DataType = { 
   content : string
   postId : string
}
```

then add it here :

```
      async (data : DataType, {rejectWithValue}) => {
```

You can read more here : https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk

Comment: if i have another dispatch like this
    dispatch(loadPost({postId: post.id}));
can i reuse this DataType??
 type DataType = { 
   content : string
   postId : string
}

Comment: you should just make the "content"  not required 
change  it to this :
DataType = { content?: string 
postId : string } 

by adding a question mark

Answer (score 0):

you specify the types in the createSlice file with either interface or type

eg:

```
interface Action {
    type: string
    payload: {
       img: string
       images: string[] | [] | null
    }
}
```

type is always string, payload is what you put in the { } inside `dispatch(addComment({content: ...payload, postId: ..payload}));`

```
interface Action {
    type: string
    payload: {
       content: string
       postId: number //or if its possibly undefined/null postId?: number | null | undefined
    }
}

const initialStateValue = {
   post: null
}

reducers: {
    addComment: (state: any = initialStateValue,  action: Action) => {
        state.post = action.payload;
    },
```